# Creating a .txt file database

Tags: python

I was wondering if anyone could help me.

I created a simple code in **python** that creates a text file with username, password, and email inputs.

The text file should look like this

```
username: 
password:
email:
time when account was made:
ip:
address:

username:
password:
etc.
```

Could anyone help me figure out how to take all the data from this file and make it log in credentials.

Here is the code:

```
# User Inputed Database in Python

import os.path
import datetime
import socket
import geocoder

ip = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())

def database():
    global username
    global password
    global email
    global directory
    global name_of_file
    global completeName
    global file1
    global info
    username = str(input('Username: '))

    if username == '' or username == ' ':
        print('Please create a valid username, no blanks!')
        username = str(input('Username: '))



    password = str(input('Password: '))

    if password == '' or password == ' ' or password == 'password':
        print('Please create a valid password, no blanks, make it strong!')
        username = str(input('Password:: '))

    time = datetime.datetime.now()
    time = str(time)
    g = geocoder.ip('me')
    address = str(g)

    email = str(input('Email (please include @....):  '))

    directory = r'C:\Users\epick\Desktop\NewDataBase'


    name_of_file = 'Database'

    completeName = os.path.join(directory, name_of_file+".txt")

    file1 = open(completeName, "a") #appending the file

    info = ('Username: ' + username +'\n' + 'Password: ' + password + '\n' + 'Email: ' + email + '\n' + 'Time account made: ' + time + '\n' + 'IP address: ' + ip + '\n' + 'Address: ' + address + '\n' + '\n' + '\n')
    file1.write(info)

    file1.close()

    login()

def login():
    open(r'C:\Downloads\Python\loginwithDatabase.py', "r")
database()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "make it log in credentials"?

Comment: It is important to know exactly how the text-file is formatted. How the username, password, email, etc... separated from each other? Do they appear on different lines inside of the text file? or are username and passwords on the same line? Are there any ***carriage return (`\r`) or line-feed characters (`\n`) separating the email from the password? What are the ***delimiters***? What separates one thing in the file from another thing in the file? Do the insides of the file look like `"email":bob@gmail.com\n"password":p1a1s1s1word\n`

Comment: better use `SQLite`. It also save in file but using SQL `query` can be very useful. Eventaully use `csv`, `json` or `pickle` for this - it will be simpler.

Comment: That is very insecure and it will be very painful to deal with it, please use a database or json atleast (still bad for thi case).